# Why is my method not seeing this.property?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

In the code below, `initializeBoard` has access to the property, and the console returns 'white' when I start the script. But when I click inside the window, I get 'undefined'. What obvious thing am I missing? (Bonus: what's the search query that'd have led me to the answer without having to ask?)

```
var view = {

  currentMove: 'white',

  initializeBoard: function() {
    console.log(this.currentMove);
  },

  click: function(e) {
    console.log(this.currentMove);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  view.initializeBoard();
  document.onclick = view.click;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by how the function **is called**, not by where it is first assigned.

You are *copying* the (reference to the) function to `document.onclick`.

When the click event happens `document.onclick` is called. `view.click` is **not** called (even though it has the same value as `document.onclick`). This means that `this` is `document` not `view`.

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you want to create a wrapper function that calls the original function in the right context.

```
document.onclick = view.click.bind(view);
```

Comment: I think that makes sense! How wrong would it be to, say, change the command in the method to "console.log(view.currentMove);"?